# Using Jquery loaded at parent window in a child frame

Tags: jquery, frame

Is it possible that i can utilize the JQuery, which i loaded in a window, at a child iframe within that window. I dont want to load jquery multiple time in frames.

Comment: Are you talking about the JQuery files uploaded or jQuery variables created in the parent window?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible however it requires some work: [inherit.js - jQuery Sharing between Parents and iFrames](http://snipplr.com/view/15393/inheritjs--jquery-sharing-between-parents-and-iframes/)

One thing to consider is that browsers will cache a resource like jQuery (assuming it is served as it typically is with headers saying it can be cached). The point being referencing the same jQuery source in both the main window and in the iframe(s) would use a cached file. So a complex work around doesn't seem particularly useful unless you need it for some other reason.